# List contains repeated items

Tags: c#, list

I was trying to do a simple task on C#, put objects into a list, I've done that before, but never encountered this problem. After a few search, encountered people with similar problems, and some solutions but none fixed my problem, here's the code.

```
static void GenerateRooms(int RoomsNumber)
    {
        int randomWidth;
        int randomHeight;
        Room newRoom = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < RoomsNumber; i++)
        {
            //Create new rooms and store it on the list
            randomWidth = rand.Next(_MinRoomW, _MaxRoomW + 1);
            randomHeight = rand.Next(_MinRoomH, _MaxRoomH + 1);

            //Room(x, y, id)
            newRoom = new Room(randomWidth, randomHeight, i);

            //1
            _RoomsL.Insert(i, newRoom);
        }
    }
```

After comment 1, I actually search the list, and all the objects are there, from 0 to the last one, but when I exit this function to any other, like that one for instance:

```
 static void CheckList()
    {
        foreach(Room nextRoom in _RoomsL)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" This room have the id: " + nextRoom.GetId());
        }
    }
```

All the objects into that list have the same Id, in that case, the id is equal to the last object added on the list on the first method...

So its like that:

```
        GenerateRooms(RoomsNumber); << at the end of this function, the list is ok.

        CheckList(); << just after exiting the last function and checking the same list, all the objects are the same.
```

I tried using `list.Insert` too, but didn't change anything. I really don't know what to do.

Room Class.

```
class Room
{
    //This is random.
    public static Random rand = new Random();

    //Room variables
    public static int rWIDTH, rHEIGHT;
    public static int ROOMID;

    public Room(int X, int Y, int id)
    {
        rWIDTH = X;
        rHEIGHT = Y;
        ROOMID = id;
    }

    public int GetWidth()
    {
        return rWIDTH;
    }

    public int GetHeight()
    {
        return rHEIGHT;
    }

    public int GetId()
    {
        return ROOMID;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your Room.GetId() method? This would be helpful.

Comment: or the Room class

Comment: why is each method static? It doesn't seem that you have stateless stuff inside you class so having everything static isn't maybe a good design. Anyway this is not a code review platform ;-)

Comment: Room class is on the post now.

i will get rid of the statics, i was so eager to test some ideas that forgot about that. thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int ROOMID;
```

If it's a static variable, it persists through any instance of the class. So make it un-static.

I suggest you rework your code to look like a standardized C# class:

First move your random variable `rand` to the calling class (so remove it from Room)

Then for your room class:

```
public class Room
{

   //Room variables
   public int Width {get;set;}
   public int Height {get;set;}
   public int RoomID {get;set;}

   public Room(int width, int height, int id)
   {
       Width = width;
       Height = height;
       RoomID = id;
   }

}
```

and get the properties like this:

```
Room room = new Room(width,height,id);
Console.WriteLine(room.Width+" is the room width");
```

etc.

Comment: Make all variables un-static :-)

Comment: ok i just feel so dumb right now xD, i made this same mistake, when i started programming and now after almost 3 years, here it is again. 

the code is working now, and i will implement your suggestions, thank you very much. :)

(i need some sleep)

Comment: No problem @JeffCarvalho , I also wrote a suggestion on how you should write your class if you want it to look a little more like standard C# code :).